# FileReader is not able to read a file from camera - Xamarin + WebView

Tags: android, vue.js, xamarin.forms, filereader

I have an APP that is only a container for a VUE PWA. In one page the user could upload some file. I implemented the following solution to give the user the option to select a file from Galery or take a new photo.

https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/building-a-hybrid-app-with-xamarin-forms/

The problem is the FileReader is not able to read the file when the user takes a new photo with the camera. if the user selects an existing file, the upload works well. This is the error:

```
FileReader: 
message: "The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired."
name: "NotReadableError"
```

I noticed one difference: when the user selects a file from galery, the URI path that the APP sent to the WebView looks like the following:

```
{content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A32681}
```

When the user takes a new photo:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JBSTRIP/IMG_637273232207442660.jpg
```

Anyone had the same problem? I didn't found any solution from web.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remove file:// from that path.

Comment: I'm not able to remove it, due is a URI object, not a string.

Comment: @AlexMarinhodeFreitas You could use `MediaPlugin`. Download the source file from the link: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: Of course you can remove it from uri.toSting(). Then create a new uri.

Comment: Thank you guys, but, I just figure it out what was happening. Solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I changed the directory where the picture from camera is saved:

Instead get the path using:

```
File imageStorageDir = new File (Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (
                    Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "APP");
```

I  used the APP's folder:

```
 File imageStorageDir = new File (_context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "APP");
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do not forget to accept answer~